# Reactjs - event.stopPropagation not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I have a `Post` component which basically render's a card. If the post is clicked, then the **URL** should route to `'/expand/'`.

Now I have another component called `DeleteTemplate` which renders a button and clicking it render's a *Modal*.

Now, I have used this `DeleteTemplate` in my `Post` component.

Now, clicking the `DeleteTemplate` button is rendering the Modal. In the Modal if i select the `Cancel` option, the **URL** is getting routed to `'/expand/'` which shouldn't be happening.

[image: Edit 4jmrwwy004]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The click events of the buttons in your modal are bubbling up to the card. You need to add `event.stopPropagation()` to the `onClick` handlers of those buttons inside the modal.

So in your `DeleteTemplate` render function:

```
<Button color="secondary" onClick={this.cancel}>
    CANCEL
</Button>
```

with the cancel handler looking like this:

```
cancel(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.toggleModal();
}
```

Working example:

[image: Edit xvw8y7l9ko]