# React Dropdown acessibility onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu

at the current point, this code works, but when the user clicks to hide the menu, the `useClickOutside` fires too, the menu toggles off and on again... would there any way to fix that so when clicks outside it closes but when clicks the button it toggles on/off ?

```
const useClickOutside = (ref, handler) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const clickHandler = (event) => {
            if (!ref.current || ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
                return;
            }
            handler(event);
        };

        document.addEventListener('mousedown', clickHandler);

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('mousedown', clickHandler);
        };
    });
};

const Settings = () => {
    const ref = useRef();
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
    useClickOutside(ref, () => setToggle(false));

    return (
        <div className='settings'>
            <button onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)} className='settings__button'>
                Menu
            </button>
            {toggle && (
                <div ref={ref} className='settings__panel'>
                    <Link className='settings__links' to='/user/settings'>
                        Your Profile
                    </Link>
                    <Link className='settings__links' to='/user/settings'>
                        Todos history
                    </Link>
                    <Link className='settings__links' to='/user/settings'>
                        Settings
                    </Link>
                    <Link className='settings__links' value={'Logout'} to='/user/login'>
                        Logout
                    </Link>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider adding a `onBlur` event on the `.settings` div with a `tabIndex=0`.

You can then then capture blurs of the div and test if the event came from within the div or not.

```
const onBlur = (e: FocusEvent < HTMLElement > ) => {
  if (opened?) {
    const element = e.relatedTarget;

    if (element == null) {
      // dropdown was blured because window lost focused. probably close.
    } else if (element != e.currentTarget) {
      if (!e.currentTarget.contains(element as Node)) {
        // blured element is not in .settings. close
      }
    }
  }
};
```

If you want to get fancy you can also add a `keydown` and close on escape.

```
const onKeyDown = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
  if (e.key === "Escape") {
    // close!
  }
);
```

Here is a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-v5im7?file=/index.js) that implements these items.

Comment: thats a lil bit hard to grasp, but ill try to work on this tip. Ty.

Comment: What do you need clarified?

Comment: "e: FocusEvent < HTMLElement>" ... "element as Node"

Comment: remove all that. its from typescript. I had an existing code sample. I also updated my post to contain a sanbox of my proposed changes.

Comment: thanks for the highlight the onBlur/onFocus existance. that simplifed my code whole a lot. I wrote it a a lil bit simpler tho. why do you need all those if/ifelse? https://codesandbox.io/s/dropdown-showcase-iokzz i set a lot of nesting stuff for testing purposes.

Comment: the `element == null` is for a blur that happens outside the dom. Say a user clicks on another tab or window. the `elements.contains` is because a blur can happen inside the dropdown. say you have a search box, checkbox, ect in the dropdown, if a user focuses into that ie clicks, you will trigger a blur and you will need to know if the blur happened from inside.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of event [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation). Add the call `event.stopPropagation()` to your onClick handler function that hides the menu.

```
<button 
  onClick={(e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setToggle(!toggle);
  }}
  className='settings__button'
  >
   Menu
</button>
```

This will prevent that the onClick event bubbles upwards to the next event listener which would be your onClickOutside listener.

UPDATE:

This will only work if your event listener is listening for onClick events. Your inline `onClick` event listener will stop the propagation of the event of type `click` only.

```
document.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);

return () => {
  document.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler);
};
```

Comment: it doesnt help :/ button keeps toggling on/off twice.

Comment: Ah I am sorry. It was not working since your event listener is not listening for click events but mouse down. If you switch to listening for click events, it will work! Also, it's a very common way to resolve your issue, see for example the same solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51441562/reactjs-event-stoppropagation-not-working

Comment: thanks andre. it will be useful for future purposes on this custom hook of mine.